# How to remove duplicate comma separated value in a single column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

[image]

```
SELECT id, country FROM my_records
```

I've got the above result from MySQL query and i want to remove duplicate ID from the result.
Not with the help of PHP code but do with MySQL query. Is there any function or query to do the same.

Thanks

Comment: Country is a column right? And NOT a result of GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: yes Country is a column also its not come from GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Can you provide the query? May be it can help us for understanding.

Comment: @JERRY-thechuha providing you the query, i am just editing my question, its a very simple query.

Comment: I don't think MySQL can efficiently do this for you.  Its string processing abilities are lacking good pattern extraction.  Are you requiring a MySQL query because you want to remove the values (via UPDATE) or are you hoping to remove this solutions logic on each query?  If you are thinking of the latter, I believe any MySQL solution will perform extremely poorly - so much that you may rethink the MySQL requirement

Answer (score 8):

I stuck into the similar situation and found that MySql does not provide any predefined function to overcome this problem.

To overcome I created a UDF, Please have a look below on the defination and usage.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `get_unique_items`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `get_unique_items`(str varchar(1000)) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

        SET @String      = str;
        SET @Occurrences = LENGTH(@String) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@String, ',', ''));
        SET @ret='';
        myloop: WHILE (@Occurrences > 0)
        DO 
            SET @myValue = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@String, ',', 1);
            IF (TRIM(@myValue) != '') THEN
                IF((LENGTH(@ret) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@ret, @myValue, '')))=0) THEN
                        SELECT CONCAT(@ret,@myValue,',') INTO @ret;
                END if;
            END IF;
            SET @Occurrences = LENGTH(@String) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@String, ',', ''));
            IF (@occurrences = 0) THEN 
                LEAVE myloop; 
            END IF;
            SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@String, ',', 1))+2);
        END WHILE;    
SET @ret=concat(substring(@ret,1,length(@ret)-1), '');
return @ret;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```
SELECT get_unique_items('2,2,2,22,2,3,3,3,34,34,,54,5,45,,65,6,5,,67,6,,34,34,2,3,23,2,32,,3,2,,323') AS 'Items';
```

Result:

```
2,22,3,34,54,45,65,67,23,32,323
```

Hope this help!

Comment: It doesn't work if there's only one value without any commas

Comment: @pee2pee I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This may helps you.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `find_duplicate_using_comma` //
CREATE FUNCTION `find_duplicate_using_comma` (in_str LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN


DECLARE out_str LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL; -- pending output
DECLARE next_str TEXT DEFAULT NULL;    -- next element under consideration

dedup:
LOOP

  IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(in_str)) = 0 OR in_str IS NULL THEN
    LEAVE dedup; -- no more data to consider
  END IF;

  SET next_str = SUBSTRING_INDEX(in_str,',',1);                   -- find the next element
  SET in_str = SUBSTRING(in_str FROM (CHAR_LENGTH(next_str) + 1 + 1)); -- remove that element

  SET in_str = TRIM(in_str), next_str = TRIM(next_str); -- trim the new and the rest

  IF FIND_IN_SET(next_str,out_str) OR CHAR_LENGTH(next_str) = 0 THEN -- if empty or already found
    ITERATE dedup;
  END IF;

  SET out_str = CONCAT_WS(',',out_str,next_str); -- append the new to pending output 

END LOOP;

RETURN out_str;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Example :

```
SELECT find_duplicate_using_comma('6675,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661,8661') AS data;

Result : 6675,8661
```

Comment: good for my case

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions given are case insensitive, If you want result to be case sensitive and NOT remove accented matches like 'o' and 'ö', and looking for exact and strict match, here is the code

If utf8mb4_bin does not work, try utf8_bin or other binary types.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `find_duplicate_using_comma` //
CREATE FUNCTION `find_duplicate_using_comma` (in_str LONGTEXT) RETURNS LONGTEXT
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN


DECLARE out_str LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL; -- pending output
DECLARE next_str TEXT DEFAULT NULL;    -- next element under consideration

dedup:
LOOP

  IF CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(in_str)) = 0 OR in_str IS NULL THEN
    LEAVE dedup; -- no more data to consider
  END IF;

  SET next_str = SUBSTRING_INDEX(in_str,',',1);                   -- find the next element
  SET in_str = SUBSTRING(in_str FROM (CHAR_LENGTH(next_str) + 1 + 1)); -- remove that element

  SET in_str = TRIM(in_str), next_str = TRIM(next_str); -- trim the new and the rest

  IF FIND_IN_SET(next_str collate utf8mb4_bin,out_str collate utf8mb4_bin) OR CHAR_LENGTH(next_str) = 0 THEN -- if empty or already found
    ITERATE dedup;
  END IF;

  SET out_str = CONCAT_WS(',',out_str,next_str); -- append the new to pending output 

END LOOP;

RETURN out_str;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```